Idea can not connect to pgsql and aways print this Error [0A000] org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: units "epoch" not supported
[0A000] org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: units "epoch" not supported at position：referenced column: startup_time
I want to connect to pasql but i can not just this error tip help me please god,my pgsql version  is PostgreSQL 9.2.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by g++ (GCC) 7.3.0, 64-bit

Looks like you are trying to run a statement that causes an error. But with as little detail as you give us, we cannot help.

Please provide screenshots of the error and data source connection settings in IDEA. For general instructions on how to connect to PSQL from within the IDE, you can refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/postgresql.html
